# PostgreSQL Function Return Type Error

Tags: postgresql

I am very new and trying to teach my self PostgreSQL. At the moment I am trying to create a function which updates a column based on the values of two other columns in the same table. I am creating the function as I want to call it as a trigger to execute when the column values are edited. All colomns are holding text.

My code is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION rev_1.update_proceed_column() RETURNS character varying AS
$BODY$
  UPDATE rev_1.catchment_e_gravity_lines SET proceed = 'N/A'
  WHERE installed = 'YES' AND dependent = 'YES'; 
  UPDATE rev_1.catchment_e_gravity_lines SET proceed = 'N/A'
  where installed = 'YES' AND dependent ='NO';
  UPDATE rev_1.catchment_e_gravity_lines SET proceed = 'YES'
  WHERE installed = 'NO' AND dependent = 'NO';
  UPDATE rev_1.catchment_e_gravity_lines SET proceed = 'NO'
  WHERE installed = 'NO' AND dependent = 'YES';$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF;
ALTER FUNCTION rev_1.update_proceed_column()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

I am however getting an error of 'return type mismatch' and cant seem to get a function working. Am I missing something?

Comment: Your update queries do not return anything, meaning this is basically `void` function and that it should be defined in the header `RETURNS void` instead of `RETURNS character..`. Also, when actually need to return char/varchar/text, then just use `RETURNS text`, the current format is incorrect anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Kristo Mägi, I adjusted the header from character to void and it now works as I need it to.